# What is the way to ensure @OneToOne relationship in Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a entity relationship setup as @OneToOne. For example (User <--> Pet)

```
@Entity
public class Pet {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = true)
  User user;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    Pet pet;            
}
```

To my surprise, Spring will allow you to assign multiple entities into the relationship (Multiple Pets associated with User) when you save via the repositories.

```
//for example:
pet.user = user1;
pet2.user = user1;
petRepository.save(pet);
petRepository.save(pet2);  //allowed
```

But then after the save, the database will now be corrupted. 
By calling petRepository.findAll or findById or anything really...will now yield this error

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1245, for class: package.models.Pet
```

So what is the proper way to ensure OneToOne relationship so as to not corrupt the db?

Comment: can you post your relevant code so that it helps us to understand where can be the problem?

Comment: seems like you're having a Collection of Pet in User entity?

Comment: You could put a unique constraint at SQL level. Also, here is a good read, especially if you want your relationship to be lazy: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/.

Comment: I guess the unique constraint could work, how do I specify that in code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126769/uniqueconstraint-annotation-in-java