# Unique Value in JPA Issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My Entity contains `Long id` attribute and i get JSON request from user with `id` value,

When i tried to save it first time, it saving, and when i tried to use same `id` in JPA save method, it is saving also. I use the below,

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long id;
```

and i tried with the below,

```
@Table(name = "Person",
        uniqueConstraints={
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
```

also not working.  My request JSON as below, and if i use the same JSON for next request also saving.

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"John"
}
```

Comment: your unique constraint is not working?

Comment: In my case the id from user JSON, yes not working. How to make them unique. Tried the above approach but no luck.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126769/uniqueconstraint-annotation-in-java

Comment: when you pass an entity with id to the save method, instead of inserting a new database record makes an update so it does not trigger the DB restriction. The operation is correct. You can try to set name as unique key and insert {"id": 1, "name": "John"} and {"id": 2, "name": "John"}

Comment: Unfortunately, i use some API, which uses inbuilt schema but it's grey area for me. That's one of the issue for me

Comment: I tried with different id and same name, it's saving also.  @AliTahir tried with ```@Table(name = "Person", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames ={"id"})})``` also no luck.

Comment: tried this? : uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "column1")}

Comment: I have tried this: @Table(name = "Person", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")) ...... and its working on my machine. You can also try removing @GeneratedValue and see if it helps.

Comment: sure,  Thanks Tahir i will try now, and keep you posted.

Comment: Tahir, i used tried, ```@Table(name = "Person", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
public class Person { @Id @Column(name = "id") private Long id;``` no luck.

Comment: well, it looks like you will have to get a list of ids from DB and check if it already exists in your service class. atm in one of my projects I'm sending requests while the user is typing a unique value for better user experience.

Comment: yeah, that's my next approach. thanks Tahir.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in code.

When you say strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY and passing the exist ID, hibernate believes that this entity already in DB because it has ID.

IDENTITY means your DB has column "id" and it auto-incremented while insert is happened.

If you always receive entity with exist ID, just remove @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) and I hope it would be okey.